# fopen ftp:// wrapper is disabled

Tags: php, ftp, fopen

I try to create a file on a remote server and write something in but every time i get the error:

```
Warning (2): fopen(): ftp:// wrapper is disabled in the server
configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 Warning (2):
fopen(ftp://...@log/TEST/CONFIG/test.proc) [function.fopen]: failed
to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found
```

I try on **local server and it works well** but when I try on my prod server (my prod server and the remote server where i try to create/write the file are different) i got the error above.

In **both** php.ini :

> allow_url_fopen= On

i do :

```
$path = "ftp://login:pass@IP/TEST/CONFIG/" . $name; // $name = test.proc
$dest = fopen($path, "w");
```

Which mistake could I have done that prevents it from working? How can I fix this?

EDIT: in `phpinfo()`, allow_url_fopen is turned off (global and local), why ? (i'm using cakephp framework, maybe ? and the server where allow_url_fopen is set at off every time is hosted by OVH)

Comment: did you check `phpinfo()` output to see if you modified the correct php.ini, or that the allow_url_fopen directive wasn't override BACK to `off` later on?

Comment: If you open a php script with only the phpinfo(); command, what does it say under allow_url_fopen global/local ? sometimes there are local php directives overwriting php.ini's.

Comment: I check phpinfo() to know where was located my php.ini but not to know the value of allow_url_open... and your right, they're both (global and local) at Off. What can overwrite php.ini directives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually check the files in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d and security.ini was overwriting some rules of my php.ini including allow_url_fopen.
Thank you for your time and help.